# Cannot write ă symbol in name during Windows 10 setup

Tags: windows-10, special-characters, ascii

I am starting a brand new PC with Windows 10 pre-installed for the very first time. Now I am stuck because I cannot write the user name with this special character **ă**.

I try to use the `Alt + ASCII code (259=ă)`, nothing happens, but it is working for `Ā ("Alt" + 256)`.

> System region: Switzerland
>
> Keyboard layout: Swiss-German
>
> Installed language packages: Maybe the one which I could select a few steps before: German - English (UK) - French - Italian

Does anyone know a solution or restriction about this character?

Comment: What region is the system set to?  What keyboard layout are you using?  What language packs are installed?  The use of these types of characters with the wrong region configured will cause you problems.  What do you mean "you cannot enter it" is that because you cannot type the ASCII code or because it rejects it?  Edit your question and provide this information

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, you can write the name without the breviated 'a' (ă).

Later, you will be able to change the user account name through Control Panel by copying and pasting the character.

Once the account is set up as an admin, go to `"Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts"`, click `"Manage User Accounts"`, and click `"Properties"`.

Now you can change the username to include the breviated 'a'.

Good luck!

Comment: I did it like you had describe...but now with the command `netplwiz` I could not change it to ă :(

Comment: [I was able to copy and paste the desired character in when testing this..](http://i.imgur.com/hbiYPJ6.png)

Comment: Create another admin account and try changing this account from that one.